# Does liquid mercury solubilize gold and other solid metals at room temperature?

Tags: solubility

Is it correct to say liquid mercury solubilizes gold and other solid metals at room temperature?

I know that mercury forms an amalgam (alloy) with some metals and I also know it is correct to say most alloys are a metallic solution. That's the why of the question.

Comment: "Solubilize" is not quite the right word; I'd better say "dissolve". Now to the point: yes, it does.

Comment: It does dissolves some metals but it also causes liquid metal embrittlement.  Essentially it dissolves grain boundaries and the metal will fail by brittle fracture although there is no damage visually apparent.

Comment: When I was in the army one of the guys was playing with some mercury [soldiers love danger] and got it on his wedding ring. Before he could get the ring off it broke into several pieces. He came running to the lab to get it fixed worried how to explain it to his wife. I put it in a plastic bottle as a keepsake.  Mercury dissolves gold very quickly.